# What's the best way to handle nested try/catch AttributeError check?

Tags: python, exception

Here's my code:

```
try:
    entry_date = entry.updated_date
except AttributeError:
    try:
        entry_date = entry.published_date
    except AttributeError:
        entry_date = manual_parse_from_string(entry)
```

In this scenario I'm parsing a feed and trying to get the date. RSS comes with `updated_date`, `published_date` or date in string format, which need further processing into the DateTime object. I have a feeling it can be done in an other way, such as in this pseudo-code:

```
entry_date = entry.updated_date
or
entry.published_date or manual_parse_from_string(entry)
```

None of those seems right to me. What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, you can use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) with a `None` default value:

```
entry_date = (getattr(entry, 'updated_date', None)
              or getattr(entry, 'published_date', None)
              or manual_parse_from_string(entry))
```

Answer (score 0):

Homogenise your different getters into uniform callables and iterate over them:

```
from operator import attrgetter

getters = attrgetter('updated_date'), attrgetter('published_date'), manual_parse_from_string

for getter in getters:
    try:
        entry_date = getter(entry)
    except AttibuteError:
        pass
```